# how to give links to the track order image to get the tracking information

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

i have added the track order image through static block in the footer,how can i give link to that image to get the tracking information.[image]

Comment: <a href="{{store url="trackorder.html"}}"><img src="/media/background/Image/1.jpg" /></a>

Answer (score 2):

Please try bellow code in static block

```
<a href="{{store url="trackorder.html"}}"><img src="{{media url="background/Image/1.jpg"}}" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: Hey try to give some other way i already given this

Comment: Can you please send your code? is image path correct?

Comment: oh sorry i missed media url

Comment: where is that trackorder.html?

Comment: insted of trackorder.html give your  tracking information page link

Comment: you can up-vote if that work for you

Comment: i m not getting which page link should give for track order,please suggest me that page link

Comment: Please use : <a href="{{store url="sales/guest/form/"}}"><img src="{{media url="background/Image/1.jpg"}}" alt="" /></a>